# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages integrated with Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I have a project with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Razor pages. The application is extremely simple: one welcome page to protect static files. My problem started when I wanted to integrate my small website with Identity Server 4.

Usually, in my other .NET Core project, in the *Startup.cs* I added:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages(options => {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Login");
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityServerConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerConfiguration"));

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".cello.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.Name = "cello.dashboard";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            IdentityServerConfiguration idsrv = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerConfiguration").Get<IdentityServerConfiguration>();
            options.Authority = idsrv.Url;
            options.ClientId = idsrv.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = idsrv.ClientSecret;
```

#if DEBUG
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
#else
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
#endif

```
            options.ResponseType = "code";

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("roles");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            };
        });
    }
```

When I try to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` I have an incompatibility error.

[image]

I have to use the version 3.1.9 of this library not the latest one.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In November 2020, Microsoft released [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/) as the next version of .NET Core. Projects targeting .NET 5 cannot be referenced from projects targeting .NET Core 3.x.x. Latest versions of [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/releases) packages already switched to `net5.0` (including [OpenIdConnect](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect) package).

To be able to use the latest version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`, you should [migrate your project to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50).

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use v 3.1.* of this library in your case. [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/3.1.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/3.1.10) is the latest compatible with .NET Core 3.1.
If you want to use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/5.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/5.0.1) your application should be .NET 5.

Also I'm not sure if there is any major changes in this package for .NET 5 except being compatible with .NET 5.